# how to choose Conv1D filter and kernel size parameter

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a 1D CNN to train data with the shape of (9922, 1000, 1) as input and (9922,)
as labels. Is there a way to determine the optimal or a reasonable filter and kernel size number for the first Conv1D layer?

Comment: Kernel size of 3 works fine everywhere, for filters start with less (maybe 32) , then keeps on increasing on next Conv1D layer by factor of 2 (such as 32, 64, 64, 128, 128, 256 .......) You could also repeat same filter size, well it's hit and trial. You can always add more depth if you think that the performance of your model is less.

Comment: i see, thank you for the advice. should i consider adding a few dense layers as well and if so, what should be my input for these dense layers?

Comment: Keep less dense layers, it does not extract much features compared to Conv layer (at least in Conv2d, not sure for 1D). Also trainable parameters increases drastically in dense layers. So, add dense layers only if you have good processing power, else 2 or 3 dense layer will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help